# event Action<> --> reference null when using modal dialog

Tags: c#, events, nullreferenceexception

I have two forms - **frm_Main** and **frm_Threshold**. The threshold form contains a trackbar.

All I need to do is to open the frm_Threshold from the frm_Main and if the trackbar changes trigger an event in the frm_Main.

I have found the solution (see the code) that seems to work, however, only if the frm_Threshold is called as a modal dialog from the frm_Main.

**frm_Threshold code:**

```
    //event to pass value of threshold if changed onto another form
    public event Action<int> ThresholdValueChanged;
    //trackbar value changed
    private void trackBarThreshold_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //changing value in the textbox
        textBoxThreshold.Text = trackBarThreshold.Value.ToString();
        //assignig value to the event to pass onto another form
        ThresholdValueChanged(trackBarThreshold.Value);
    }
```

**frm_Main code:**

```
    private void toolStripButtonThreshold_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm_Threshold formThreshold = new frm_Threshold();
        formThreshold.ThresholdValueChanged += new Action<int>(Threshold);
        formThreshold.ShowDialog();    // if changed to .Show() throws exception                 
        formThreshold.ThresholdValueChanged -= new Action<int>(Threshold);
    }

    private void Threshold(int value)
    {
       // do something
    }
```

In case I call the frm_Threshold form using the *Show()* method, null reference exception on the

```
  public event Action<int> ThresholdValueChanged
```

is thrown (in the frm_Threshold).

Any idea how to solve the issue? Thanks!

Comment: What exception are you seeing? Do you need to remove the event? It will be cleaned up automatically when your form goes out of scope. However when you use .Show the code continues to run and unbinds the event immediately.

Comment: Aaah, I see that. The exception is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". I forgot that the code continues so I basically subscribe to the event, open the dialog and then unsubscribe. After removing the   'FormThreshold.ThresholdValueChanged -= new Action<int>(Threshold)' everything works fine. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Good!  Maybe I should have posted this as an answer instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line:

```
formThreshold.ThresholdValueChanged -= new Action<int>(Threshold);
```

If you just call the form using .Show() you immediately remove your event again.
By the way, you don't need this line in any case.